# How to get ListBox1.Selected(i) position and change style?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to automatically add buttons to user form in position rigth to selected item in list box.

in excel sheet I'm adding buttons like

```
Sub buttonsAdd()
   Dim btn As Button
   Dim t As Range
   LastRow = wsAuth.Cells(wsAuth.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
   wsAuth.Buttons.Delete       
   For i = 1 To LastRow
     Set t = wsAuth.Range(wsAuth.Cells(i, 6), wsAuth.Cells(i, 6))
     Set btn = wsAuth.Buttons.add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
     With btn
        .OnAction = "btnS"
        .Caption = SignInButCaption & wsAuth.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Name = "Btn" & i
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .AutoSize = False
     End With
   Next i
End Sub
```

Is there a way to add buttons to userform in the same position as listbox.selected(i)?
Is it possible to change listbox.selected(i) font size and style?

Comment: 1) _"Is there a way to add buttons to userform in the same position as listbox.selected(i)?"_ :somehow it is. but I'd choose some other different approach  2) _"Is it possible to change listbox.selected(i) font size and style?"_: to my knowledge, you can change the font and style of the whole listbox